# SP Online modern ui: reformat date in managed property column

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, react, date

Using SP Online, trying to show a friendly format date (without time) in the SPFx modern search results web part.

I've mapped the date column to a preset managed property of type date. That displays as:
**4/9/2020 4:00:00 AM** (standard format and with time)

I've mapped a calculated column that includes the date value to a preset managed property of type text. That displays as:
**string;#April 09, 2020** (friendly, no time, but with "string;#" at the start.

Has anyone found a way to get a date like this to display as: **April 09, 2020**? So either remove the time from a date type managed property or remove the "string" text from a text type managed property? This would be easy with jQuery but that's not available in this environment. And when I tried a simple javascript string.replace, it did nothing.